# Error message given: Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred

Tags: swiftui

I have tried many things, but seem to be getting continuous error messages which I cannot remove. The code is listed below, and I have the following questions:

1. Where is the error? The second ForEach statement has no errors, but the first results in "Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred".
2. Why can't I use a "for" statement within this block? When I do so, I get an error message
3. It's strange not to define i and j upfront, but when I do so I get error messages. Why?
4. I would like to make the various (8) circle segments which are drawn buttons. I have found references in older Swift versions (see commented lines below), but how should I create those in SwiftUI?

Any help to this beginner would be much appreciated.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    static let segmentCount = 4
    static let circleCount = 2

    var body: some View {

        let r = CGFloat(75.0)
        let center_x = CGFloat(150.0)
        let center_y = CGFloat(150.0)
        var arc_start = CGFloat(45.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)

        let arc_length = CGFloat(90.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
        var arc_width = CGFloat(25.0)
        let line0Target_x = center_x + r * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start)))
        let line0Target_y = center_y + r * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start)))
        let line1Target_x = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))
        let line1Target_y = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))

        ZStack {
            ForEach(1..<ContentView.circleCount){ j in
                r = CGFloat(25.0 + CGFloat((j) - 1.0) * 25.0)
                ForEach(1..<ContentView.segmentCount){ i in
                    Path { path in
                        arc_start = CGFloat((45.0 + (CGFloat(i) - 1.0) * 90.0)) * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: r, startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), clockwise: false)
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line1Target_x, y: line1Target_y))
                        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: (r + arc_width), startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), clockwise: true)
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                        path.closeSubpath()

//                        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
//                        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//                        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
//                        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile, because you are adding `let`s and `var`s in `body` closure, where compiler expects some `View`.
You can simply move your vars inside of `Path` closure (or you can make some functions for computing it):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static let segmentCount = 4
    static let circleCount = 2

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(1..<ContentView.circleCount){ j in
                ForEach(1..<ContentView.segmentCount){ i in
                    Path { path in
                        let r = CGFloat(25.0 + (CGFloat(j) - 1.0) * 25.0)
                        let center_x = CGFloat(150.0)
                        let center_y = CGFloat(150.0)
                        var arc_start = CGFloat(45.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)

                        let arc_length = CGFloat(90.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
                        var arc_width = CGFloat(25.0)
                        let line0Target_x = center_x + r * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start)))
                        let line0Target_y = center_y + r * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start)))
                        let line1Target_x = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))
                        let line1Target_y = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))

                        arc_start = CGFloat((45.0 + (CGFloat(i) - 1.0) * 90.0)) * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: r, startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), clockwise: false)
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line1Target_x, y: line1Target_y))
                        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: (r + arc_width), startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), clockwise: true)
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                        path.closeSubpath()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```